# What is the best fix, for mouseleave (over select) bug?

Tags: jquery, firefox, select, internet-explorer-9, mouseleave

```
#childBox {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border:solid thin #900;
}


<div id="parentBox">
    <div id="childBox">
        <select>
            <option>Opt1</option>
            <option>Opt2</option>
                <option>Opt3</option>
            </select>
    </div>
    <div id="mesIn"></div>
    <div id="mesOut"></div>
</div>


var i = 0, y=0; 
$('#parentBox').on({
    mouseenter:function(e){ 
        //console.log ('in: ');
      i++; $('#mesIn').text('IN '+i); 
    },
    mouseleave: function(e){    
      //console.log ('out: ');
      y++; $('#mesOut').text('OUT '+y); 
    }
}, '#childBox');
```

When the mouse enters the options it will fire first as 'out' and then as 'in' again.
I found this prb in FF23 & IE9 (FF is crashing)
It's working as it should in Chrome 28 & Opera 12.16
I have jquery 1.10.02

For above code: http://jsfiddle.net/buicu/ZCmRP/1/
For a more detailed version of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/buicu/ZH6qm/4/

I know I could put a bunch of setTimeout/clearTimeout. But I want something more simple/cleaner.

e.stopImmediatePropagation(); doesn't help (at least in my test.).

To bind a click to select (and to set false a variable) doesn't help either. Because if the select drop down menu remains open and then the mouse leaves the big menu, then the big menu will also remain open (I know I could track when the mouse leaves the options and change back the variable. But checking when the mouse leaves the option can't be done consistently across browsers).

Does anyone has a simple/cleaner fix for this bug?

Comment: did you try `e.stopPropagation();` (as opposed to `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`) ?

Comment: @asifrc Yes, without success.

Answer (score 4):

```
mouseleave: function(e){    
  //console.log ('out: ');

  /* Solution */
  if(e.relatedTarget == null) return;
  /************/

  y++; $('#mesOut').text('OUT '+y);
}
```

Comment: Works - but only as long as the entire select box (all options) is inside the parent element where mouseleave is declared.

Comment: In Chrome it worked properly but I had to do this hack for Firefox and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

post was created a long time ago but in Google this topic is actual, so probably will be useful to someone.

basically you can to use this solutions:

```
jQuery('#parentBox').mouseleave(function(){}, function(e){
    if (e.target == this) {
        console.log('leave');
    }
    else {
        console.log('false');
    }
});
```

but in my case I am using this :

```
jQuery('#parentBox').mouseleave(function(){}, function(e){
    if (jQuery('#parentBox').find(e.toElement)) {
        console.log('leave');
    } 
    else {
        console.log('false');
    }  
});
```